# VBA assign cell value based on another cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I get nothing in Sheet2.Cells(7,2) when cell(7,1) is "Shift". Already tried .value and .text, same result.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  If Sheet2.Cells(7, 1).Value = "Shift" Then
  Sheet2.Cells(7, 2).Value = "ASTM D638"
  End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Huh worked for me XD You sure it's exactly "Shift"?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure.

Comment: Welp, not sure what to tell you. Works for me XD I presume you're not getting an error?

Comment: Try `worksheets("Sheet2")` instead of `Sheet2`.  It may be that the code name is referring to the wrong sheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner oooo good point. I assumed OP knows exactly what he wants.

Comment: Trim the value:  `If Trim(Sheet2.cells(7,1).value) = "Shift" Then` Just to clear out any whitespace happening in there. Also, note that the `=` operator is case sensitive in VBA... There's no reason why your code wouldn't work as is besides that.

Comment: @JNevill, yes! you are right. I put some spaces in front of the 'Shift", it works with your help.